# Dice equal percentage

Tags: probability, dice, percentages

There are 2x 20 sided dice.

According to [anydice.com](http://anydice.com/), "*output 2d20*" has a probability percentage mean of 5.0% (The chance of getting a 21) on 2x 20 sided dice.

Say, I wanted the probability to be evenly distributed among 5 categories, each having 20% chance equaling 100%.

Example:

A - ~20% probability 
 
B - ~20% probability 
C - ~20% probability 
D - ~20% probability 
E - ~20% probability

Which *sequencing* numbers would each category have to reach an evenly (or closely even) distributed probability of rolling two 20 sided dice? What is the mathematic formula for coming up with this distributed probability of rolling?

Comment: It is very unclear what you want. It sounds like you're saying that the chance (probability?) of getting a 21 is $5=500\%$, which clearly is wrong. What do you mean by categories? Are they outcomes? I'd suggest you rewrite your question with a reader that knows *nothing* about your scenario in mind.

Comment: Do you want to use 2 20-sided dice to decide fairly among 5 possible outcomes? Then throw away one of them, and use just the other: 1-4, 5-8, 9-12, 13-16 and 17-20 are five equally likely categories.

Comment: I have rewritten the question to be more clear. I need to have 2 dice, because there additionally needs a probability to have doubles.

Comment: Ignore the second die and if the first one is $1-4$, $E$, $5-8$, $D$, etc.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to partition the sample space so that each part in the partition has equal probability?

Comment: And how do you want doubles to be distributed?  Equally among the five categories as well?  I will point out that there is no one single way to do this, there are *many* different ways.  Some will seem more complicated than others.  The easiest way I can think of would be just adding the two results and looking at it modulo five.  That each category is equally represented can be seen using a conditional probability argument.  Further, since $5$ is prime, we even get that the doubles are equally distributed too.

Comment: That is to say, if I roll an 18 and a 5, this corresponds to a sum of $23$ and so would be category $3$ (or *C* if you prefer letters).  If I roll a 5 and a 15, this corresponds to a sum of $20$ and so would be category $5$ (or *E* if you prefer letters), etc...  (*specifics can be shifted around however you like, if you prefer remainder0 to correspond to category A and remainder 3 to correspond to category D or whatever, so long as you are specific*)

Comment: The probability of doubles is $1/20$, so partition the roll on one die as Thomas Andrews suggested, and do whatever it is you were going to do on doubles when the second die shows a $20$.

Comment: @amd the difficulty comes into play when we are unable to distinguish between a "first die" and a "second die."  [A video by Matt Parker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHh0ui5mi_E) describes a similar puzzle (and eventual solution) where we roll three indistinguishable six-sided dice and wish to partition the results into categories to simulate having rolled only two.  As such, reference to "first die" or "second die" are often not allowed and we are allowed only to roll the dice once.  I'm aware that the OP hasn't explicitly stated those rules, but they make problem more interesting/useful.

Comment: @JMoravitz I’m of course assuming that the dice can be distinguished, since this question seems an awful lot like something for a game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must throw two such dice, then the probability distribution of their sum has  $P(S=s) = \dfrac{20 - |s-21|}{400}$ for $2 \le s \le 40$,

and so the following five patterns of sums are equally probable:

- $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13$ or $39$
- $14,15,16,17,18$ or $36$
- $19,20,21,22$ or $37$
- $23,24,25,26,27$
- $28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35$ or $38$ or $40$

though there are many other partitions which also achieve this

Answer (score 2):

Easier to remember than @Henry's proposed partition

The following five patterns of sums of two fair d20's are equally probable:

- $1,6,11,16,\dots,36$
- $2,7,12,17,\dots,37$
- $3,8,13,18,\dots,38$
- $4,9,14,19,\dots,39$
- $5,10,15,20,\dots,40$

Simply look at the last digit of the sum.  Sums whose last digit is a $1$ or $6$ correspond to the first category while sums whose last digit is a $2$ or $7$ correspond to the second category etc...

Rolling two of a same number are equally distributed among these as well: $(3,3),(8,8),(13,13),(18,18)$ all belonging to the first category: $(1,1),(6,6),(11,11),(16,16)$ all belonging to the second category, etc...

That these are equally represented follows from the observation that each die is equally likely to have any possible remainder modulo 5.